# Is there a way to extract data from a PDF form and use it to generate a report in LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, report

I tried to search for this question but failed. I hope it is not a duplicate. I am trying to automate the process of summarizing a long PDF form. I want to extract data from certain fields in a PDF form and then put it together into a PDF report within LaTeX. The PDF form is not made in LaTeX but rather in Adobe Acrobat Pro. Is their a way in LaTeX to "Suck in" Data from a saved PDF form and reuse it ?!

Comment: You may want to look for FDF, this is - as far as I understand it - the technical platform for PDF forms. I doubt that there is any LaTeX-only way to access this information.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Thank You. If it is -as you said- can't be done entirely in LaTeX then I might do it in a 2-step process of extracting the PDF form data into spreadsheet or a CSV file then using LaTeX's Datatool to get the data into LaTeX. It is a bit lenghty but it is the only workaround I can think of.

Comment: Acrobat Pro can save the PDF for example as XLSX, from there you could work your way through. You can also save the form contents as FDF or XML. If you would like to see an example, send me an email at <mylastname>@gmail.com and I can extract it for you (if you have no Acrobat Pro)